# Run Caffe as CPU-only after a successful GPU Caffe installation

Tags: docker, caffe, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I have a Docker image with Caffe compiled with cudnn support. CUDA and all other dependencies are installed correctly in the image and it works correctly when using `nvidia-docker` to provide drivers from the host machine.

I would like to run this same image *without* using `nvidia-docker` and just set Caffe to CPU mode. However, when I do this, I still see errors that the correct Nvidia drivers can't be found. It's as if building Caffe with cudnn support causes Caffe to *require* the GPU drivers. This is problematic for my use case: providing one single Docker image that can be used interchangeably as either a CPU-based image or a GPU-based image.

How can I install Caffe with cudnn / GPU support enabled, but still run it with no runtime dependency on any CUDA / GPU dependencies?

Note: this is not a question about disabling GPU support with a `CPU_ONLY` flag during Caffe build time. Rather, it's about taking Caffe built to be able to use the GPU, but then run it in a manner that doesn't require any drivers, CUDA libraries, etc., in a CPU-only *runtime* mode.

The type of error I see at runtime is below:

```
I0523 21:09:42.175459    14 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1
I0523 21:09:42.175561    14 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1
I0523 21:09:42.175606    14 net.cpp:406] conv1 <- data
I0523 21:09:42.175660    14 net.cpp:380] conv1 -> conv1
F0523 21:09:42.177079    14 cudnn_conv_layer.cpp:52] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)  CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here I am just loading a prototxt model *after* calling `caffe.set_mode_cpu()` using Caffe's Python binding.

If I compile in CPU_ONLY mode, everything works, or if I actually run with nvidia-docker on a machine hosting the right drivers. But I'm specifically looking for a single Docker image that would be portable between host machines that both do and do not have GPUs or the necessary driver dependencies.

Comment: it looks like the network you are using explicitly defined a layer that should run using cuda udnn_conv_layer.cp, F0523 21:09:42.177079    14 cudnn_conv_layer.cpp:52] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0) here is the closest discussion i could find to your problem..it suggest to swittch the engine to caffe ..it would be even helpful if you could post your prototxt file here... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/Hc6c4KVaXkQ/2RIMGaPwEIEJ

Comment: The network does not define any properties that depend on GPU or CUDA. If I use CPU_ONLY flag, everything works as expected with exactly the same trained network. Note that it is *Caffe's choice* to use the `cudnn_conv_layer` despite `caffe.set_mode_cpu()` -- this doesn't happen when making forward passes on the network in CPU_ONLY mode.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the prototxt file as it is for a work-related project, but this is trivially easy to reproduce with any pre-trained model that doesn't rely on GPU solver, etc. Just run it in GPU host with Caffe installed with cudnn support, but try plain `docker` and `set_mode_cpu`.

Comment: well..not sure...but i think this might be similar issue https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows/issues/37

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan that is helpful -- if that hasn't been changed in more recent Caffe versions, it suggests that use of `USE_CUDNN` and `CPU_ONLY` are mutually exclusive, which is nuts but I guess it's good to know the limitation is intrinsic to Caffe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging, [this reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/Hc6c4KVaXkQ/hS7QJWKjU_EJ) suggests that it is the `LayerSetup` function for particular convolution layers causing the problem.

In particular, in [cudnn_conv_layer.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/31a18c222f6541369c6d70b30958f6c4c1ab7ab2/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp), the LayerSetup implementation makes calls to [CUDA_CHECK and CUDNN_CHECK](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/31a18c222f6541369c6d70b30958f6c4c1ab7ab2/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp#L53) for e.g. CUDA stream handling.

It looks like when Caffe is compiled with cudnn support, these checks will fail if you attempt to execute in CPU mode, even after `set_mode_cpu()`. I am not sure whether a change to the `CUDNN_CHECK` macro would be sufficient, or if it requires [writing a totally new Caffe layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development) that checks the runtime mode before determining which resource checks to perform. Either case is not workable for my current situation, so I'll split out CPU and GPU functionality into two separate Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should be able to make that choice by simply setting `solver_mode` in `solver.prototxt` or some similar setting.  However, that's not how BVLC designed Caffe; there are various other links in the code that assume it can avail itself of the GPUs implied by the CUDA code's presence.

The solution would be to dig through the code, find the references to the CUDA presence flags, and alter the code to dynamically use the "CPU_ONLY" branches when your `CPU` flag was set.

Comment: I'm unclear about this. What does `set_mode_cpu()` do if not allow for exactly this even when in an environment in which CUDA has been installed? In other words, how does `set_mode_cpu` route everything to CPU yet still have some dependence on CUDA?

Comment: I was down in the code last autumn, but I'm afraid I don't remember just where that stumbling block was.

Comment: Does the [answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228112/567620) agree with your previous experience in the Caffe code?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I disabled the check macro, as that compilation would never use a GPU.

Comment: So, the only option is to build caffe again without GPU support?